# I can not create Navigation Drawer Activity on Android Stuido

Tags: java, android

I want to create a navigation drawer activity in my Java project, but it does not occur.I get an error like:Class referenced in the manifest, com.example.gezi.MainPageActivity, was not found in the project or the libraries.
I have a navigation drawer activity named menusayfasiActivity in my project. I want to redirect this activity, which is a menu after the user login page, but it does not happen. So I want to create a new navigation drawer activity but it does not.
I'm new to Android programming. I would be glad if you could help me

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gezi" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Gezi" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainPageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_page"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Gezi.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".bos" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MenusayfasiActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_menusayfasi"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Gezi.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".kayitol" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
/>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: can u share the code of your AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: I shared the code

Comment: remove '/>' from line number 32 and then try to run

Comment: unfortunately the error did not fix

Comment: try once by removing "android:theme="@style/Theme.Gezi.NoActionBar" from MenusayfasiActivity in Manifest file

Comment: unfortunately the error did not fix